# Best way to handle constraint violations when using EJB 3.0 and CMP

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0, jax-ws

I have a web service (built using jaxb/jaxws) that invokes a stateless EJB to store some data in the database. The data is being stored as an entity bean. The entity bean has a unique constraint applied to it via the `@Column(unique = true)` annotation.

When the web service attempts to save data, the transaction fails, and rightfully so. The problem is that since I am using CMP, the transaction is not committed until after the call to the stateless EJB. The end result is that I am not able to trap the exception and it is getting funneled up to the WS stack and results in an ambiguous fault containing the string: `Error committing transaction:;nested exception is: weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException`.

Is there a way to catch the exception being thrown so I can provide more information to the caller? Thank you.

Version information:

- Application Server: Oracle Weblogic 10.3
- Persistence Provider: Hibernate 3.2.5.ga (JPA 1.0)
- JDK/JRE: 1.6_0_05 (provided by Weblogic install)

Update:
I tried to implement an EJB 3 interceptor around the method invocation and this does not appear to work.

```
public class TestInterceptor {

@AroundInvoke
public Object logCall(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Invoking method: " + context.getMethod().getName());

    try {
        return context.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("I caught an exception: " + t.getMessage());
        throw new Exception(t);
    }

}
```

The reason I think this doesn't work is because the processing chain is such that the actual persist happens outside of the method (of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [Bean Validation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/package-summary.html). It's nicely connected with the JPA (invoked during pre-persist, pre-update and pre-remove phases and can be used in different layers of your application.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, if a validation constraint violation occurs, the transaction is marked for rollback... I don't know how you could cope with that but one (seems nasty and **untested**) way I could think of is to inject a ValidatorFactory and validate the object by yourself. Perhaps then you could catch the ValidationException.

**EDIT:** I'm not sure if the Bean Validation was available in Java EE 5.

**EDIT 2:** You can create an interceptor which will catch the exception thrown by the JPA (or more precisely by the database). As the interceptor is invoked as a part of the same transaction as the EJB method you might need to explicitly invoke EntityManager#flush(-) to synchronise changes with the database.

Comment: I am not familiar with Bean Validation, but it seems to me that even if the bean was validated, by the time the object is actually persisted in the database, a constraint validation related to a unique field could have occurred so the problem still remains. You are correct in that Bean Validation does not appear to be available in JEE5.

Comment: @babernat yes, as said - Bean Validation occurs during pre-* phases so if you want to check the DB constraints you can check them only during real access to the DB. You might remember that you can catch the runtimeException and throw some `@ApplicationException` which better resembles what actually happened. You could do that in an Interceptor to decouple this from your business logic.

Comment: I tried the interceptor approach (see edited question), but it appears the transaction commits after my interceptor is called so I cannot trap it using the interceptor. That is unless I wrote my interceptor incorrectly.

Comment: You might want to invoke an explicit flush on the used EntityManager.

Comment: Explicitly flushing the EntityManager does work and I can catch the resulting exception and handle it. +1 and accepted answer for the help.

Comment: Glad it worked. I've updated the answer to reflect what we were talking about here.